# Django crispy forms inline label and input field

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a Django ModelForm containing 3 fields: name, lastname, email. What I want is to adjust the crispy form to have each field along with it's label in one line, so the form will look like this:

```
Name: <input name>
Lastname: <input lastname>
Email: <input email>
<button Submit>
```

I tried with FormHelper and Layout and bootstrap inline attribute but all I achieved was having all elements in the form in one line.

I'm really bad at frontend and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your settings.py contains:

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

you probably want to override the template `bootstrap4/field.html` which is the one that places the label and the various possible input field together.

to do so, you can copy the `templates/bootstrap4/field.html` file from the crispy_form package into your `templates/bootstrap4/field.html` in your application and have it modified as per your needs. When the template engine will render the form fields, it will find your modified `field.html` before the one in the original template.

you may also want to be refered to the template pack `uni_form` which, without css, renders the fields almost the way you want. You can use it as is or get yourself inspired by the way it is structured to modify your own `field.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve my goal by simply changing `{{ my_form|crispy }}`  to `{{ my_form.as_p }}`  in my html code.